# remove item selected of first comboBox from second comboBox c# windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am having a problem:

I am making a Windows Forms application in C#.

The problem I'm having is I have 4 `ComboBoxes`, and when I select an item from `comboBox1` that item should be removed from `comboBox2`, `comboBox3` and `comboBox4`.

Similarly, the selected item from `comboBox2` should be removed from `comboBox3` and `comboBox4`, and so on.

I have tried this but can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should code something like this in your comboBoxes selectedChange events:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < comboBox2.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (comboBox2.Items[i] == comboBox1.SelectedItem)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox2.Items[i]);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

it works if your items are string, if you have custom object you should cast items and then compare specific property on them like id for example.

Comment: I think I have figured it out now, THANKS FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: I have a small problem, say if i got 6 items in a comboBox if i was to click an item then chnage my mind it will remove both the items i have selected

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? as i understood, when you select an item it will remove from another combobox but remain in current combobox! ;)